# key not found: regParam in Logistic Regression PredictionIO

Tags: logistic-regression, predictionio

I am using `TextClassificationEngine`. Given example at https://docs.prediction.io/demo/textclassification/ there is two algorithms (Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression) for text classification. Naive Bayes algorithm works fine but when I used Logistic Regression it gives some error.

```
{
  "id": "default",
  "description": "Default settings",
  "engineFactory": "org.template.textclassification.TextClassificationEngine",
  "datasource": {
    "params": {
      "appName": "Logistic"
    }
  },
  "preparator": {
    "params": {
      "nGram": 2
    }
  },
  "algorithms": [
    {
      "name": "regParam",
      "params": {
        "regParam":2,5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

above code is given on site, it have some error at `regParam` due to array. Can anyone please explain me what `regParam` in `engine.json` and what is the final `engine.json` for Logistic regression?

Comment: the error is because you have `"regParam":2,5` with a comma, not `"regParam":2.5` with a period. @EmergentOrder explains how it's used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mistake in the doc, I'll submit a pull to fix it.

regParam is expecting a double, so something like 
`"regParam":0.1`

Specifically, this param is used (in Spark ML) for L2 regularization, 
which reduces the chance of overfitting [where the model does not generalize well] by penalizing models for being too complex.

The exact value to use is an empirical problem, 
I would suggest if you are concerned about the value to do some search over the space of values for regParam, using a held-out validation set (or k-fold) to determine the winner.